# Undefined variable projects laravel, I tried to read data from the database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question. I try to read some data out an database. I use Laravel and I get an error that the var projects is undefined.

In **project.blade.php** I have this code.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Project naam</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($projects as $project)

            <tr>
            <td>{{$project->project_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->project_name}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

In web.php I have this

```
Route::get('projects','StudViewController@index');
```

And in **StudViewController.php** I've got this

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class StudViewController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $projects = DB::select("SELECT * FROM projects");
        return view("projects",["projects"=>$projects]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Change your query to : DB::table('projects')->get();

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should works.

```
class StudViewController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $projects = DB::table('projects')->select('*')->get();
        return view("projects",compact('projects'));
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this also dosn't works. Do you mabey need more information or code from me to see what i do wrong?

Comment: @Jelmer Check Edited Answer

Comment: i've got this error ```Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException```

Comment: `$projects = DB::table('projects')->select('*')->get();` USe this @Jelmer

Comment: @jelmer check my answer.

Comment: undifined variable projects

Comment: @Jelmer check not empty condition in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to :

```
DB::table('projects')->get();
```

Ex:

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index() {
        $projects = DB::table('projects')->get();
        return view("projects",compact("projects"));
    }
```

There is a small typo in view file name, Rename your view file with projects.blade.php instead of project.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code following way:

In `project.blade.php` file

```
<table>
<thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Project name</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if(!empty($projects))
        @foreach ($projects as $project)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$project->project_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$project->project_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</tbody>
```

In Controller:

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use DB;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class StudViewController extends Controller {

  public function index() {
    $projects = DB::table('projects')->get();
    return view("project", ["projects" => $projects]);
  }
}
```

*if your blade file name `projects.blade.php` then user `return view("projects", ["projects" => $projects]);`